# Apply foreign key and check constraint to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, check-constraints

My question boils down to something like 'Can join table B be subject to a check constraint against a value in table A which is not a foreign key?'. The situation may be further complicated by multiple references to the same Foreign Key. The specific scenario I am struggling with is detailed below with some abbreviated MySQL code.

A MySQL database contains the table 'Disorder' (shown below):

```
CREATE TABLE `Disorder` (
disorder_name VARCHAR(255),
disorder_type VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY(`disorder_name`)
)
```

The disorder type can be either 'syndrome' or 'disease'. Diseases and syndromes can be linked in a many-to-many fashion (e.g. several diseases can be caused the same syndrome and the same disease may cause different syndromes).

I wish to create a join table called 'DiseaseSyndromeLink' showing the relationship between disorders that are 'diseases' and disorders that are 'syndromes'.

```
CREATE TABLE `DiseaseSyndromeLink` (
`ds_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `disease` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`syndrome` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ds_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (disease) REFERENCES disorder(disorder_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (syndrome) REFERENCES disorder(disorder_name)
)
```

This table needs constraints that are tricky to design:

- The first column is a integer join ID
- The second column 'Disease' is a foreign key referencing Disorder.disorder_name. Only disorder_names where Disorder.disorder_type='Disease' should be allowed to be entered here.
- The third column 'Syndrome' is a foreign key referencing Disorder.disorder_name. Only disorder_names where Disorder.disorder_type='Syndrome' should be allowed to be entered here.

I feel the syntax should be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `DiseaseSyndromeLink` (
`ds_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`disease` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`syndrome` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ds_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (disease) REFERENCES disorder(disorder_name) WHERE (Disorder.disorder_type='Disease'),
FOREIGN KEY (syndrome) REFERENCES disorder(disorder_name) WHERE (Disorder.disorder_type='Syndrome')
)
```

My understanding is that checking values (e.g. ='Disease') requires a check constraint whereas linking to the original table requires a foreign key constraint. I cannot find any docummentation or YouTube tutorials detailing using BOTH these constraints simultaneously. As it has been very hard to find any examples of this code I wondered whether I have made a mistake with respect to database design but cannot think of a good alternative.

Can check and foreign key constraints be used together like this?

Thanks for your time!

***QUESTION EDITED AS ORIGINALLY CONTAINED INFORMATION ABOUT TRYING TO ENFORCE THIS RELATIONSHIP AT THE DJANGO SIDE.***

Answer (score 0):

As I see the your MYSQL statement kinda worked, so all you need to do is add foreign key in the same way to the model like you did. Although this time, you will set 'null=True' and if you have unique values then 'unique=True' this will take care of empty columns. Now you have to implement rest in application logic while adding data, you have to be aware 'where disease type' , etc criteria. But when you are reading from the database Django will automatically prefetch related. Example query for reading data.

```
data=Diseasesyndromelink.objects.filter(disease__feild="query")
print(data.disease) #your foreign key object is prefetched here already.
```

Check out the documentation for more examples.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input! A little unclear regarding this sorry - are you suggesting filtering choices and then using these in the model or applying a filter directly to the model column. I have never come across an example of either of these in the models.py file (all filtering I have seen so far is in the view). I could filter at the view level for the admin.py file but this leaves no constraints on the underlying table.

Comment: Hey, Yes, I was saying, first, you create two foreign keys in models. You execute the filter from the query itself without view logic for reads Diseasesyndromelink.objects.filter(disease__feildname="search"). See those '__' they allow you to access and filter the disease table field if it is a foreign key in Diseasesyndromelink. Did I understand it correctly? If yes then I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm still not quite sure we are on the same page. I need to ensure that a disorder which has disorder_type="disease" cannot be entered in the DiseaseSyndromeLink.syndrome field.

Are you suggesting instead of:

class DiseaseSyndromeLink(models.Model):
    disease = models.ForeignKey('Disorder', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='disease', related_name='disease')

I have something like:
class DiseaseSyndromeLink(models.Model):
    disease = Disorder.objects.filter(Disorder__disorder_type="Disease")

I can't reconcile the above syntax with also defining the field as a ForeignKey

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. As far as you are talking about 'disorder which has disorder_type="disease" cannot be entered in the DiseaseSyndromeLink.syndrome field' you have to implement that in application logic or models custom methods. What I was telling you a read query in ORM. If there is confusion, could you please update the question as to what you expect, and what you want, there are many things you discussed in the question

Comment: Thanks for your time. Sorry the original question proved difficult to answer - it was too complicated and poorly phrased. I have re-structured the question based on your responses. I think it would be preferable to enforce the constraints on the MySQL side. I think editing forms in Django will be relatively easier than making the changes I think you are proposing to models.py which I simply cannot follow. I have only ever seen code like yours in Django views and would not know where to start applying it elsewhere! Sorry for the inconvenience.